# 'value.length' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript

What's causing this error? Should I pass element.value into the function? I know how to set this up in a JSP, but not in JavaScript. I'm having trouble passing values into another function.

```
function editCommentToggle( id )
{
    theRow = document.getElementById("id"+id);
    //user = theRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
    //date = theRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
    com = theRow.cells[2].innerHTML;


    idx = 2;
    maxlength = 250;
    // Comment field

    cell = theRow.cells[idx];
    while( cell.childNodes.length > 0 )
        cell.removeChild(cell.childNodes[0]);
    element = document.createElement("textarea");
    element.id="comments-"+id;
    element.rows="3";
    element.value = com;
    element.style.width = "400px";
    element.maxLength = "250";
    element.onfocus = element.onkeydown = element.onkeyup = function(){
            return characterCounterEdit(undefined, maxlength, element);
    }; 
    cell.appendChild(element);



function characterCounterEdit(id, maxLen, inputElement)
{
    spanId = document.getElementById(id);

    if (spanId)
    {
        // Update the counter the user sees.
        var whatIsLeft = maxLen - inputElement.value.length;

        if ( whatIsLeft < 0 ) whatIsLeft = 0;
        spanId.innerText = whatIsLeft;
    }

    // Restrict user from entering more than the maxlen.
 **ERROR HERE-->>>**   if ( inputElement.value.length > maxLen )
    {
        inputElement.value = inputElement.value.substring( 0, maxLen );
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried? We are not an automated code-debugging machine.

Comment: I tried passing "element" in the funtion by itself

Comment: Please return with a question, preferably formed with at least a few English sentences. Preferably sentences with which you have taken some care and attention, instead of a smattering of typos and lack of punctuation!

Comment: thanx for the heads up!...those other guys helped me out nicely!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing this ...

```
element.onfocus = element.onkeydown = element.onkeyup = function(){return characterCounterEdit(undefined, maxlength, element);};
```

to this ...

```
element.onfocus = element.onkeydown = element.onkeyup = function(){return characterCounterEdit(undefined, maxlength, this);};
                                                                                                                     ^^^^
```

or you could also try using the event target/sourceElement, described here - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html - in your `characterCounterEdit` function.

Comment: I'm glad it fixed your problem. Seems a few people were a bit quick closing this question and didn't really give you a chance to get it fixed so you actually asked your question. Hopefully a few lessons learnt on both sides :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    element.onfocus = element.onkeydown = element.onkeyup = function(){return characterCounterEdit(undefined, maxlength, element);};
```

If this is theonly place that your characterCounterEdit function is called, then by the time the focus/keydown/keyup events are triggered, `element` has most likely been assigned some OTHER value, which doesn not have a .value attribute.

Instead of passing in `element` and `maxlength`  (which may not exist anymore at the time the event(s) are triggered, do this:

```
element.maxlength = maxlength
element.onfocus = element.onkeydown = element.onkeyup = function(){return characterCounterEdit();}; 

function characterCounterEdit() {
    ....
    var whatIsLeft = maxLen - this.value.length;
                                     ^^^^--- use 'this' instead.
    ....
    if ( this.value.length > this.maxlength ) ...
    ....

}
```

Comment: Hey buddy, thanx for that...i just changed element to 'this' and that worked like buddy said below.  Im gonna try it your way also to see if thats an alternative...appreciate it!